# Eclipse Classic presentation style

Tags: eclipse

The "presentation" settings under Appearance are completely missing in the newer versions of Eclipse (don't know when it was removed).

I'm quite addicted to what was called:

- "Default" presentation under older Eclipse versions (3.1),
- "3.0 Presentation" under Eclipse Europa (3.3),
- "Classic Presentation" under Eclipse Helios (3.6), etc.

Attached a screenshot from Helios, with emphasis on the particularities that I want: **multiple tiles with individual minimize/maximize buttons.**

Any way to have this under newer versions (Eclipse Oxygen 4.7)?
Thank you.

Eclipse Helios Classic presentation
[image: Eclipse Helios Classic presentation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of Eclipse was completely rewritten for Eclipse 4 and all styling is now done using CSS.

Unfortunately the rewrite dropped the presentation override and you can no longer do this.

It is possible to split the editor area vertically or horizontally using drag and drop but you can't get individual minimize controls.